# No me reconoce un Getter en una función con ArrayList

Tags: java, poo, netbeans

No me reconoce el getter "getNombre" en el Main cuando recorro el ArrayList y lo llamo.
"agenda.get(i).getNombre()". NetBeans me dice "Cannot find Symbol".
Lo curioso es que si que puedo hacer la llamada al getter en la función Main pero no en otras funciones.
Tiene que ser algo parecido al scope de JavaScript ya que le paso el ArrayList como parámetro de la función.
El .get() funciona perfectamente pero al querer dentro del .get() llamar a .getter() no me detecta el getter.

**Contacto.java:**

```
package agenda;

public class Contacto {
private String nombre;
private int telefono;

public Contacto(String nombre, int telefono) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Contacto{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", telefono=" + telefono + "}";
}

}
```

Aquí el main
**Main.java:**

```
package agenda;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainAgenda {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Contacto> agenda = new ArrayList<Contacto>();
    
    
    agenda.add(new Contacto("Juan Sáez García",665020636));
    agenda.add(new Contacto("Ivan Soriano Zapata",876845432));
    agenda.add(new Contacto("Francisco Javier Peris",997745248));
    
    Menu(agenda);
}

public static void Menu(ArrayList agenda){
    boolean llave = true;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
    
    do {
        System.out.println("1.Ver Agenda\n1.Buscar Contacto\n3.Añadir Contacto\n4.Borrar Contacto\n5.Salir");
        int op = sc.nextInt();

        switch(op){
            case 1 -> VerAgenda(agenda);
            case 2 -> BuscarContacto(agenda);
            case 3 -> AñadirContacto(agenda);
            case 4 -> BorrarContacto(agenda);
            case 5 -> llave=false;
        }
    } while (llave);  
}

public static void VerAgenda(ArrayList agenda){
    System.out.println("\n--AGENDA--");
    for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(agenda.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

public static void BuscarContacto(ArrayList agenda){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println("\n Introduce un nombre: ");
    String nombre = sc.nextLine();
    boolean a = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i++) {
        if(agenda.get(i).getNombre() == nombre){
            System.out.println(agenda.get(i));
            a = true;
            i = agenda.size();
        }
    }
    if(a==false){
        System.out.println("No se ha encontrado ningún contacto\n");
    }
}
public static void AñadirContacto(ArrayList agenda){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println("\n Introduce su nombre: ");
    String nombre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\n Introduce su teléfono: ");
    int telefono = sc.nextInt();
    agenda.add(new Contacto(nombre, telefono));
}
public static void BorrarContacto(ArrayList agenda){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println("\n Introduce un nombre: ");
    String nombre = sc.nextLine();
    boolean a = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i++) {
        if(agenda.get(i).getNombre() == nombre){
            agenda.remove(i);
            System.out.println("Contacto Borrado");
            a = true;
            i = agenda.size();
        }
    }
    if(a==false){
        System.out.println("No se ha encontrado ningún contacto\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ArrayList es genérico, y no le has indicado el tipo. Prueba a declarar el parámetro como `ArrayList<Contacto> agenda`, o hacer un casteo en línea: `if(((Contacto) agenda.get(i)).getNombre() == nombre)`

Comment: @JuanBer por favor marca como aceptado una de las respuestas como aceptado si te fue útil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que indicar un tipo de elemento al `ArryList<T>` que usas como parámetro, porque al no hacerlo se lee como genérico y `java` no lee **atributos de objetos** de tipo genérico.
Entonces cambia los parámetros de tus métodos a:

```
public static void Menu(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda){ ... }
public static void VerAgenda(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda){ ... }
...
// todos los métodos que usas como parámetro ArrayList
```

Entonces ahora podrás usar **"agenda.get(i).getNombre()"**.
También veo que tienes otro problema al comparar cadenas, cambia el simbolo de `==` por `equals()`.
Resultado final de tu código:

```
public class MainAgenda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Contacto> agenda = new ArrayList<Contacto>();

        agenda.add(new Contacto("Juan Sáez García",665020636));
        agenda.add(new Contacto("Ivan Soriano Zapata",876845432));
        agenda.add(new Contacto("Francisco Javier Peris",997745248));
        
        Menu(agenda);
    }

    public static void Menu(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda){
        boolean llave = true;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
        
        do {
            System.out.println("1.Ver Agenda\n1.Buscar Contacto\n3.Añadir Contacto\n4.Borrar Contacto\n5.Salir");
            int op = sc.nextInt();

            switch(op){
                case 1 -> VerAgenda(agenda);
                case 2 -> BuscarContacto(agenda);
                case 3 -> AñadirContacto(agenda);
                case 4 -> BorrarContacto(agenda);
                case 5 -> llave=false;
            }
        } while (llave);  
    }

    public static void VerAgenda(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda){
        System.out.println("\n--AGENDA--");
        for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(agenda.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void BuscarContacto(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println("\n Introduce un nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        boolean a = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i++) {
            if(agenda.get(i).getNombre().equals(nombre)){
                System.out.println(agenda.get(i));
                a = true;
                i = agenda.size();
            }
        }
        if(a==false){
            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado ningún contacto\n");
        }
    }
    public static void AñadirContacto(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println("\n Introduce su nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\n Introduce su teléfono: ");
        int telefono = sc.nextInt();
        agenda.add(new Contacto(nombre, telefono));
    }
    public static void BorrarContacto(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println("\n Introduce un nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        boolean a = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i++) {
            if(agenda.get(i).getNombre().equals(nombre)){
                agenda.remove(i);
                System.out.println("Contacto Borrado");
                a = true;
                i = agenda.size();
            }
        }
        if(a==false){
            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado ningún contacto\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todos tus mètodos deben definir usar un `ArrayList` de elementos tipo `Contacto`, si no defines el tipo no podrà obtener sus getter (`agenda.get(i).getNombre()`) o setter.

Modifica tu còdigo de esta forma:

```
    package agenda;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MainAgenda {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Contacto> agenda = new ArrayList<Contacto>();

        agenda.add(new Contacto("Juan Sáez García", 665020636));
        agenda.add(new Contacto("Ivan Soriano Zapata", 876845432));
        agenda.add(new Contacto("Francisco Javier Peris", 997745248));

        Menu(agenda);
    }

    public static void Menu(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda) {
        boolean llave = true;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");

        do {
            System.out.println("1.Ver Agenda\n1.Buscar Contacto\n3.Añadir Contacto\n4.Borrar Contacto\n5.Salir");
            int op = sc.nextInt();

            switch (op) {
                case 1 -> VerAgenda(agenda);
                case 2 -> BuscarContacto(agenda);
                case 3 -> AñadirContacto(agenda);
                case 4 -> BorrarContacto(agenda);
                case 5 -> llave = false;
            }
        } while (llave);
    }

    public static void VerAgenda(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda) {
        System.out.println("\n--AGENDA--");
        for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(agenda.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void BuscarContacto(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println("\n Introduce un nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        boolean a = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i++) {
            if (agenda.get(i).getNombre() == nombre) {
                System.out.println(agenda.get(i));
                a = true;
                i = agenda.size();
            }
        }
        if (a == false) {
            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado ningún contacto\n");
        }
    }

    public static void AñadirContacto(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println("\n Introduce su nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\n Introduce su teléfono: ");
        int telefono = sc.nextInt();
        agenda.add(new Contacto(nombre, telefono));
    }

    public static void BorrarContacto(ArrayList<Contacto> agenda) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println("\n Introduce un nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        boolean a = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i++) {
            if(agenda.get(i).getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombre)){
                agenda.remove(i);
                System.out.println("Contacto Borrado");
                a = true;
                i = agenda.size();
            }
        }
        if (a == false) {
            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado ningún contacto\n");
        }
    }
}
```